# Protect sensitive data by sending the client side to the server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, socket.io

I'm working with node.js, using [socket.io](http://socket.io)

I have something like:

index.html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Server.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

But sometimes I try to send data to the server are much more sensitive and complex than a simple `"hello"`.
In this case, any user can open a console and put the same script but changing the `"hello"` value with any other.

In my app, I send the coordinates from a user that authorizes me to get it to the server, and, if he lies in a specific city, can use the app, otherwise, throws an message.

But, what if any user opens the console and send another coordinates?

Comment: Have you considered using something like backbone.js to manage your data outside the visible realm of code? Then you could separate the actual structure of your data form the end user, and it would drastically reduce your likelyhood of this situation?

Comment: The MVC pattern? I don't know how to use backbone.js

Comment: I'm not very skilled with it either, but the times I've used it to separate data from the DOM has been invaluable. If security is at all a concern, look into it (or even ember.js)

Comment: If you don't trust the client browser, yet the browser sends "sensitive" data ... then the server needs to validate it. Never trust the client. There's no API or framework that will in a reasonable way make it so your API/application can't be hacked. Obfuscation won't help. **Backbone.JS would do nothing for this.** The browser can be made to "lie" as well as other client side tools. Even an IP address could be spoofed. Either accept that most people are honest and won't take the time to send improper coordinates or find another way to authenticate users where you have a better level of trust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All critical data should be ensured by using SSL. To hide the critical information from third-party eyes we can use a token based application.